# String between two "*" or "_" characters not getting bold or italic

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, formatting

Suppose there is string wrapped with two * characters (from both starting and ending). The resulting string should be converted in bold text, similarly as when the string is wrapped with two characters _, which should produce an italic string.

My code in React is the following:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [boldText, setBoldText] = React.useState('' as any);
  const [res, setRes] = React.useState('' as any);

  let speChar: any = '*_~`';
  let openingTagsList: any = {
    '*': '<b>',
    _: '<i>',
    '*_': '<b><i>',
    '_*': '<b><i>',
  };
  let closingTagsList: any = {
    '*': '</b>',
    _: '</i>',
    '*_': '</b></i>',
    '_*': '</b></i>',
  };
  let openingTagsListKeys = Object?.keys(openingTagsList);
  let closingTagsListKeys = Object?.keys(closingTagsList);

  function strFont(e) {
    let str = e.target.value;
    let matchedSplChar = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (matchedSplChar.indexOf(str[i]) === -1) {
        if (speChar.indexOf(str[i]) !== -1) matchedSplChar += str[i];
      }
    }

    if (matchedSplChar as any) {
      let FL = str[str.indexOf(matchedSplChar, 0)];
      let SL = str[str.indexOf(matchedSplChar, 1)];
      
      let startingTags;
      let closingTags;

      for (let key in openingTagsListKeys) {
        if (matchedSplChar === openingTagsListKeys[key])
          startingTags = openingTagsList[matchedSplChar];
      }
      for (let key in closingTagsListKeys) {
        if (matchedSplChar === closingTagsListKeys[key])
          closingTags = closingTagsList[matchedSplChar];
      }

      if (FL && SL && FL == SL) {
        let replaceTags = str
          .replace(FL, startingTags)
          .replace(SL, closingTags);

        let divTag = document.createElement('div');
        divTag.innerHTML = replaceTags;
        let htmlObj: any = divTag.firstChild;

        if (htmlObj.innerHTML) setRes(htmlObj);
        setBoldText(e.target.value);
      } else {
        setBoldText(e.target.value);
      }
    } else {
      setBoldText(e.target.value);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={boldText || ''} onChange={(e) => strFont(e)} />
      {res ? <res.tagName>{res?.innerHTML}</res.tagName> : ''}
      <TextFormation />
    </div>
  );
}
```

, gives the output:

[image]

, instead of both strings being bold. How can I achieve it then?

Comment: Please post a ***[mcve]*** of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. We do NOT need your REACT code if your issue is plain JS split and wrap

Comment: I presume there's a reason you're not using MarkDown or an already existing MarkDown parser for this type of thing.

Comment: you can reason it by looking for the words which has * in the end. hint: words are seperated by spaces.

Comment: Questioning the `*`-enclosing syntax, what about e.g. `*foo*bar*baz*`? Should it be recognized and rendered as **`foo`** `bar` **`baz`** or following the OP's logic either as **`foo bar baz`** or as **`foobarbaz`**?

Comment: @PeterSeliger rendered as **foo** **bar** **baz**

Comment: @KavyaPathak ... which effectively means that [anything in between two `*` characters is going to be wrapped into `<b/>`](https://regex101.com/r/by0erj/1), like e.g. ... `foo *bar*   *baz*   *foo` ... becoming ... `foo <b>bar</b> <b>   </b> <b>baz</b> <b>   </b> *foo` ... which renders ... "foo **bar** **___** **baz** **___** *foo".

Comment: @PeterSeliger yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above comments ...

> *"@KavyaPathak ... which effectively means that [anything in between two `*` characters is going to be wrapped into](https://regex101.com/r/by0erj/1) , like e.g. ... `foo *bar*   *baz*   *foo` ... becoming ... `foo <b>bar</b> <b>   </b> <b>baz</b> <b>   </b> *foo` ... which renders ... "foo **bar** **__** **baz** **__** *foo".*" –  Peter Seliger
>
> > *"@PeterSeliger yes*" – Kavya Pathak

In case the OP's confirmation remains, the commented link to a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) based approach already represents one possible solution.

Both regular expressions ...

- [`/\*([^*]+)(?=\*)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/by0erj/1)
- [`/_([^_]+)(?=_)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/by0erj/2)

... follow the same pattern.

- match a control character (either `*` or `_`) ... `\*` respectively `_` ..,
- match and [capture](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) any character sequence which does not contain such a control character ... `([^*]+)` respectively `([^_]+)` ..,
- until a [positive lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookahead) ... `(?=\*)` respectively `(?=_)` ... confirms the presence of the next such control character (which excludes this very character from the entire match).

```js
function getMarkupFromPseudoMarkdown(value) {
  return value
    .replace(/\*([^*]+)(?=\*)/g, '<b>$1</b> ')
    .replace(/_([^_]+)(?=_)/g, '<i>$1</i> ')
    .replace(/\n/g, '<br\/>')
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
    .trim();
}
function displayCreatedMarkup({ currentTarget }) {
  const markup = getMarkupFromPseudoMarkdown(currentTarget.value);

  document.querySelector('code pre').textContent = markup;
  document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = markup;
}
document
  .querySelector('textarea')
  .addEventListener('input', displayCreatedMarkup)
```

```css
textarea, output { width: 49%; }
output { float: right; font-size: 87%; margin-top: 2px; }
code pre { background-color: #eee; white-space: break-spaces; word-break: break-all;}
```

```html
<textarea cols="32" rows="8" placeholder="... put pseudo markdown here ..."></textarea>
<output></output>
<code><pre></pre></code>
```

And in case the OP figures that the above approach does not solve the OP's problem especially not for some **bold**/*italic* edge cases, then the OP might consider a mainly [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach which handles such edge cases by looking up the previous (`matchList[idx - 1]`) and the next (`matchList[idx + 1]`) (control) character of a matching (neither `*` nor `_`) token.

```js
function getMarkupFromPseudoMarkdown(value) {
  return value
    .split(/(\*)/)
    .reduce((markup, match, idx, matchList) => {
      if (match !== '*') {
        if (
          matchList[idx - 1] === '*' &&
          matchList[idx + 1] === '*'
        ) {
          markup = `${ markup } <b>${ match }</b> `;
        } else {
          markup = `${ markup }${ match }`;
        }
      }
      return markup
    })
    .split(/(_)/)
    .reduce((markup, match, idx, matchList) => {
      if (match !== '_') {
        if (
          matchList[idx - 1] === '_' &&
          matchList[idx + 1] === '_'
        ) {
          markup = `${ markup } <i>${ match }</i> `;
        } else {
          markup = `${ markup }${ match }`;
        }
      }
      return markup
    })
    .replace(/\n/g, '<br\/>')
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
    .trim();
}
function displayCreatedMarkup({ currentTarget }) {
  const markup = getMarkupFromPseudoMarkdown(currentTarget.value);

  document.querySelector('code pre').textContent = markup;
  document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = markup;
}
document
  .querySelector('textarea')
  .addEventListener('input', displayCreatedMarkup)
```

```css
textarea, output { width: 49%; }
output { float: right; font-size: 87%; margin-top: 2px; }
code pre { background-color: #eee; white-space: break-spaces; word-break: break-all;}
```

```html
<textarea cols="32" rows="8" placeholder="... put pseudo markdown here ..."></textarea>
<output></output>
<code><pre></pre></code>
```

Comment: @KavyaPathak ... _"that's what I was looking for"_ ... which one of the approaches, the first, the second, both?